# JavaScript compiler error - Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I currently have a script in Google Tag Manager, which when I am going ot publish, is giving me x 2 JavaScript compiler errors

```
JavaScript compiler error   

Error at line 3, character 7: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: const declaration.

Error at line 4, character 18: This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: arrow function.
```

Here is my code:

```html
<script>
    (function() {
      const h4 = document.querySelectorAll('.h4');
      h4.forEach(el => {
        el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/sweater/gi, 'jumper');
      });
    })();
</script>
```

This is working correctly in DevTools. Is there a one size fits all resolution for these errors, or is it bespoke depending on your code?

Thanks,

Comment: According to Google 'Sandboxed JavaScript is based on ECMAScript 5.1. Some ECMAScript 6 features such as arrow functions and const/let declarations are available.' - https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/sandboxed-javascript. But it looks like they aren't allowed when you publish. The only robust solution is not to use them I guess, or can you just target EcmaScript 6 when you publish?

Comment: @Toby, that goes only for custom templates. Custom HTML tags do not support ES6 at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know google tag manager. Perhaps you can set that up to support ECMASCRIPT6.

If you want it to work on an older version of ECMASCRIPT then you can replace `const` with `var` and use an anonymous function instead of an arrow function.

```js
(function() {
  var h4 = document.querySelectorAll('.h4');
  h4.forEach(function(el) {
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/sweater/gi, 'jumper');
  });
})();
```

```html
<h4 class="h4">Black sweater</h4>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks for the resolution and feedback Mark